# Juntar dois objetos em um outro objeto

Tags: javascript, array, angularjs, angular, objetos

Eae galera queria saber como pegar dois objetos e juntar tudo em um terceiro objeto
falo dois objetos pois o angular esta dizendo que eles sao objetos e nao arrays.

```
      var obj1 = ['1', '02', '5'];
      var obj2 = ['ana', 'fia', 'tina'];
      vm.obj3 = [{codigo: '', nome:''}];

        //deixando assim
        vm.obj3 = [{
            {codigo: '1', nome: 'ana'}, 
            {codigo: '02', nome: 'fia'}, 
            {codigo: '5', nome: 'tina'}
        }];
```

Answer (score 3):

Pra fazer isso você vai precisar ter certeza de que as variáveis `obj1` e `obj2` estão com a mesma quantidade de itens e com a ordem que você precisa correta.

```js
var obj1 = ['1', '02', '5'];
var obj2 = ['ana', 'fia', 'tina'];

var final = [];
obj1.map((o,i) => {
    final.push({codigo: obj1[i], nome:obj2[i]})
})

console.log(final)
```

Comment: vlw cara ajudou muito